# Chain rule question for derivative of inverse

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, chain-rule

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I understand the graphical proof of $f^{-1'}[a] = {1\over f{'}[f^{-1}(a)]}$, but I'm stuck on one aspect of the simple non-graphical proof. Start with $y = f^{-1}(x)$, and thus $x = f(y)$. If we then take $$f(f^{-1}(x)) = f(y) = x$$ and do implicit differentiation with the chain rule, we get $$\mathrm{f^{'}[y]}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{{dy\over dx}} = 1$$ and the rest follows when you note that ${dy\over dx}$ at $a$ is $f^{-1'}[a]$.

All works out well when you take $f^{'}[y]$ to be ${df\over dx}(y)$. And here's where I get stuck: this is not the derivative that you get when you apply the chain rule (it seems to me, at least). Applying the chain rule to a composition of functions gives the following:  $${d\,g(h(x))\over dx} = \mathrm{dg\over \mathbf{dh}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{dh\over dx}$$ and NOT $${d\,g(h(x))\over dx} = \mathrm{dg\over \mathbf{dx}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{dh\over dx}$$ So what the differentiation should really give is: $$\mathrm{{df\over dy}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{{dy\over dx}} = 1,\,\,\,\mathrm{in\,other\,words\!\!:}\,\mathrm{{df\over df^{-1}}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{{dy\over dx}} = 1$$ This gives a very different result. Example: suppose $f = x^{2}$ so that $y = \sqrt{x} $. On the one hand, ${df\over dx} = 2x$, but on the other hand, ${df\over dy} = \mathrm{df\over dx}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{dx\over dy} = \mathrm{2x}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{2y} =
4x^{{3\over 2}}$. What am I missing?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After you arrive at the following equation
$$f'(y)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$

you can just substitute the value of $y$ to arrive at the final answer. This way could save much of your confusion.

What you seem to have done is the following:

When you say that

$$\frac{df}{df^-1}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$

you're absolutely right. But, $f = x$ and $f^-1 = y$. So this equation is essentially the same as

$$\frac{dx}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$

which is still correct, but all it implies is that

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

which is simply an obvious fact, but one that doesn't take you closer to what you're trying to prove.

So, in reality, your math is actually fine.

**The mistake is in your example.**

In your example, $f^{-1}{'}(x)$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and not $\frac{df}{dy}$

So, $f^{-1}{'}(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}x^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

You can then easily see that $f'(f^{-1}(x)) = f'(\sqrt(x)) = 2\sqrt(x)$. So the original result you wanted to prove does hold good even in this example.

***The confusion is because you've used the same variables to mean different things in your proof and example***

Hope it helps!